# can't put two textfield values together

Tags: jquery

I have two `textfield`s one filled out locally and the other getting it's value form an `ajax` query. I need to put the two textfields values together. the value of the local `textfield` is read but the other seems to be `undefined`.

```
var firstname = $("#id_of_textfield_with_local_value").val();
var lastname = $("#id_of_textfield_with_remote_value").val();
var combined = firstname + "-" + lastname;

$("#combined").val(combined);
```

the code above prints the following in the `textfiled` with `id=combined` : `reza-`
in fact the `lastname` must appear after the dash sign!

What should I do for it ?

Comment: is the remoteValue text box filled before this code gets executed?

Comment: Based on the output you show the second value is blank, not undefined. When is the code you've shown called?

Comment: no the remote value gives out just nothing.. yes nnnnnn it is blank

Comment: the code is called when the result is arrived from the other file. in fact i can access it in it's own textfield but cant put them together!

Comment: Perhaps if you showed an extract from your actual code we could advise further. (I'm assuming your actual code doesn't use those ids.)

Answer (score 1):

your code seems just fine.

#### According to question

**"getting it's value form an ajax query"**

as you're trying to set value of second text field within `ajax`, so you should try above code within that `ajax` callback. Outside of `ajax` callback you can get first text field value, but not the second one.

Comment: I suspect the missing "#" is a typo in the question, because otherwise the output would be completely blank rather than including the first name.